# Turn based redstone system

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-legacy-console

I'm trying to build a map in Minecraft on PS3, so far I've build a redstone counter. You can select up to 4 players and the counter counts up which player has to play.

But I have no idea how I can set it up so when a player isn't playing, say player 4, I can make the counter skip that guy so it's back to player 1. The same with when someone dies, I have to skip that player.

For example:

- Player 1 is plays
- Next up is player 2, but player 2 dies
- So it's up to player 3, then 4, then it loops back to player 1.
- But then I'd like to skip player 2 because he died on his previous turn, and continue on to player 3.

Here's a little bit more information:
So basicly you spawn in a room where you can see 4 buttons , each button has its own color, there's red, green, blue and purple. It also says player 1,2,3 and 4. If you are with 3 players , player 1 presses the button where it says 'player 1' and player 2 presses button 2 and so on. Then you click the lever the game starts and the redstone lamp next to player 1 starts blinking, indicating it is player 1 its turn. Player 1 stands above 2 pistons and presses the button . With a randomizer he has chance to fall or not fall. Once he presses the button the redstone lamp at player 2 starts blinking indicating its hes turn, but imaging he pressing the button he falls and dies. All that i have figurated out with redstone. The only thing i dont know what to do is when a player is not playing , example player 3 and 4 , and what happens when they die, i might be able to detect it when they die but i have no idea how to skip a players redstone lamp from blinking, because when there are only 2 players, once the third time pressing on the button happens, the 3rd redstone lamp starts , but i dont want that to happen because that player hasnt joined, i'd like to skipp 3rd and 4th player so its back to player 1.

Comment: Can you describe what you already have in more detail? If you can give us a question more along the lines of "How do I fix this" rather than "Can you write a guide for me" it's much more likely to get useful answer.

Comment: Are the players identified by any kind of ID objective? Have you got something set up to detect when they die?

Comment: This sounds like vanilla Redstone so far. Are you fine with command block based solutions?

Comment: @colorfusion: i was thinking when the player selected dies, he falls into a lava pit wich has presure plates underneath, so when he dies it will detect like so. Thanks already for trying to help !

Comment: @MrLemon: its on the ps3, no command blocks there :(, i forgot to mention i'm sorry. Also thanks for trying to help i apreciate it alot!

Answer (score 1):

I play only on Minecraft for PC, but the concepts should all be the same. The basis for my solution is to have a tripwire at the bottom of the hole into which a player falls (pressure plates will work too, but require a slightly different method of collecting a redstone signal). This tripwire triggers a non-sticky piston which pushes a block (any solid block will do), completing a shortcut which re-routes the redstone around that player's turn. To accomplish this, we will need to use the fact that redstone repeaters can collect the signal *from* a block which has a charge being put into it. An illustration of this would be `[r][B][>]`, where `r` is the activated redstone dust, `B` is the solid block, and `>` is the redstone repeater. As long as `r` is activated, `>` will also be activated. In the case below I use `[>][B][>]`, which works in the same way, but allows two redstone circuits to run side-by-side without interfering with each other. Note: `>` and `<` for repeaters represents the way the repeater is facing.

**From a top-down view, this is my solution:**

```
    ┌-[B][t]===[t][B]          [B] => solid block
    |                          [t] => tripwire hook
    └--------┐                 [p] => normal (non-sticky) piston
             |                 [>] => redstone repeater
            [p]    ┌---2        =  => string
       ┌-[>][B][>]-┘            -  => redstone dust
   1---┴-[>]   [>][>]--3   
                                1  => entering redstone signal
                                2  => runs if player is alive (go to P2's turn)
                                3  => runs if player is dead (skip to P3's turn)
```

See the picture below if you are still confused:

[image: My solution for skipping a dead player]